# "Invalid JSON" when trying to POST

Tags: json, swift, post, swifty-json

I'm attempting to POST json data to a Booking Service API.

But when I hit submit, I receive a **400 error** resulting in an **"INVALID JSON"** message.

```
let urlToRequest = "https://api.bookeo.com/v2/customers?secretKey=" + secretKey + "&apiKey=" + apiKey

func dataRequest() {
        let url4 = URL(string: urlToRequest)!
        let session4 = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url4)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


        let dataParameters: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newParameters)
        request.httpBody = dataParameters
        //request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("api.bookeo.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
        request.addValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
        request.addValue("gzip,deflate", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")


        let task = session4.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json as Any)
                } //catch {
                    //print(error)
                //}

            }


            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("*****This is the data 4: \(String(describing: dataString))") //JSONSerialization
        }
        task.resume()

    }
    dataRequest()
```

My parameters: (the "invalid JSON")

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
        "eventId": eventId,
        "customer": [
            "firstName": FirstName.text!,
            "lastName": LastName.text!,
            "emailAddress": EmailAddress.text!,
            "phoneNumbers": [
                "number": "123456",
                "type": "mobile"
            ]
        ],
        "participants": [
            "numbers": [
            "peopleCategoryId": peopleCategoryId,
            "number": 1
        ],
    ],
        "productId": productId,
        "initialPayments": [
            "reason": "Initial deposit",
            "comment": "This is a custom comment",
            "amount": [
                "amount": "0",
                "currency": "USD"
            ],
        "paymentMethod": "creditCard"
        ]
        ] as [String : Any]
```

My error response:

```
*****This is the data 4: Optional({
"httpStatus": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON",
"errorId": "1555Q180214041018NWE6T"
})
```

I've used this exact method before using JSON that was formatted the same. So I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: You’re sending binary plist (with keyed archived), not JSON. Why did you comment out the`NSJSONSerialization`? What form is the server expecting the request?

Comment: @Rob Please elaborate.

Comment: You’re preparing the body of the request with `NSKeyedArchiver`. That doesn’t build JSON. It is sending back a response saying that the request was not properly formatted.

Comment: @Rob Okay, I've switched back and I'm now using `NSJSONSerialization`. It is still returning an "Invalid JSON" response.

Comment: Then it’s probably then saying that the JSON you sent doesn’t contain what it expected. We can’t comment on that without more info about what it’s expecting in the JSON.

Comment: Could you try printing the result of this? `try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)` maybe for some reason it's becoming nil.

Comment: Unrelated to your question here, but you might want to replace `NSString` with `String` and your `NSMutableURLRequest` constant (`let`) with a `URLRequest` variable (`var`). These were introduced in Swift 3 and result in more natural code with less syntactic noise. But, again, that’s unrelated to your problem here. Just a FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your issue:

```
let dataParameters: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newParameters)
```

Don't use `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData` to serialize json; it serializes the object in a completely different way than you want for json.

**Option #1**

Use `JSONSerialization.data` instead:

```
let jsonDictionary = [ "testObject": [ "1": 2", "3": "4"]]
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:jsonDictionary, options:.prettyPrinted)
```

**Option #2**

Make a struct that conforms to the `Codable` protocol:

```
struct Parameters: Codable {
    let value1: String
    let value2: String
}
```

and serialize this way:

```
let parameters = Parameters(value1: "test1", value2: "test2")
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(parameters)
```

**Further Note:**

To validate that `jsonData` is as expected, use this code:

```
print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8))
```

This will print the json to the console as a string so you can verify the json is valid and meets server-side expectations.